# Is there a script to enable aws guard duty through CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to enable Amazon web services guard duty service in all available regions.

Is there a way to enable all the regions through the Amazon web services command line interface?

Comment: Brushed up minor grammatical errors and added more white space to enhance readability.

Comment: Strangely, couldn't see an **Enable** API call on [guardduty — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/guardduty/index.html).

Comment: is there any tutorial that i can follow??

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the answer is `aws guardduty create-detector --enable --region <your-region>`
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/guardduty/create-detector.html